# issue while logging object

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, logging, nslog

I have class containing

.h file.

```
@interface NewsItem : NSObject
{
NSString* _newsID;
NSString* _newsTitle;
NSString* _imageURL;
NSString* _description;
}
 @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString* newsID;
 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* newsTitle;
 @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString* imageURL;
 @property (nonatomic, copy)   NSString* description;
```

.m file

```
 @implementation NewsItem
 @synthesize newsID= _newsID;
 @synthesize newsTitle= _newsTitle;
 @synthesize imageURL = _imageURL;
 @synthesize description= _description;
```

Whenever I print the object of newsItem from breakpoint, the value of description field is displayed instead of object reference address.
Why so ?

Help Please, Thanks in advance.

Comment: First thing: you don't have to declare private variables in curly brackets in `@interface` file if you declare properties to. Xcode made it for you automatically under the hood. `@synthesize` is also unnecessary. Remove it and leave only properties. `_newsID, _newsTitle`, _imageURL and _description` will be available.

Comment: You should also change name of `description`, unless you consciously override `-description` of `NSObject` class.

Comment: And please add some bigger snippet of code. How do you create and use this class? Please paste code where error occurs.

Comment: @TomaszSzulc - Thanks, I think the problem was I used the field description.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have made the [`[NSObject description]`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSObject/description) method a property.  Remove `_description` and `@property description` and implement the `description` method yourself:

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"newsID=%@, newsTitle=%@, imageURL=%@", self.newsID, self.newsTitle, self.imageURL];
}
```

This method will then be called whenever you do the following:

```
NSLog(@"%@", newsItem);
```